# addScript() not work on Joomla System Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, joomla, stylesheet

I'm developing a Joomla system plugin and I need to add some scripts in the header, I've the following code:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

class PluginSystemMyPlugin extends JPlugin {
    function PluginSystemMyPlugin(&$subject, $config){
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
        $this->_plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('system','myplugin');
        $this->_params = new JParameter($this->_plugin->params);
        $this->_mainframe= &JFactory::getApplication();
        if($this->_mainframe->isAdmin())return;
    }
    function onAfterInitialise(){
        if($this->_mainframe->isAdmin())return;
        $loadjquery = $this->params->get('loadjquery');
        $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
        if($loadjquery=='yes'){
            JHTML::_(' behavior.mootools');
            $document->addScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js");
        }
        $document->addScriptDeclaration('
            jQuery.noConflict();');
    }
}
```

I've also tried addScriptDeclaration(), addStyleSheet(), addStyleSheetDeclaration(), none working. My Joomla version is 1.5.23. 
I've tried others plugin with the same declarations in onAfterInitialise() and they worked, why not mine?

Comment: How do you know its not working. Is there an error, or do they not appear. If they don't appear, do you have <jdoc:include type="head" /> in your template? Does your plugin have a database entry and is published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the errors:

```
class PluginSystemMyPlugin extends JPlugin {
    function PluginSystemMyPlugin(&$subject, $config){
```

must to be:

```
class plgSystemMyPlugin extends JPlugin {
    function plgSystemMyPlugin(&$subject, $config){
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed it correct? Have you published it? Are you sure that your plugin is run? Have you tried to debug your plugin code with `die` function to detect whether it works? Also you could try this http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML/addCustomTag